# Generate a date schedule that executes only on weekdays

Tags: php, schedule, dateinterval

I have a date schedule function in PHP which aims to execute only on working days. The code I have at the moment is generating the schedule for all days of the week so the while statement doesn't seem to working and I'm not sure why.

I'm a student, so I'm not very experienced with this kind of thing. Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static function generate_date_schedule($tasksperdayschedule, $startdate) {
    $schedule = [];

    $date = clone $startdate;

    foreach ($tasksperdayschedule as $numberoftasks) {
        $day = (int)$date->format('N');

        // Skip weekend days.
        while ($day > 5) {
            $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
            $day = (int)$date->format('N');
        }

        $schedule[$date->format(self::DATE_FORMAT)] = $numberoftasks;

        $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
    }

   return $schedule;
```

It is probably something very small I am missing, but any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: I checked it and it seems to be working fine and skipping weekends. Can you explain what input and output you are expecting?

Comment: It's a small part of a much larger code base, maybe the problem isn't with this function but lies elsewhere. It's expected to create a schedule which is then passed in elsewhere to send out notifications.

Answer (score 1):

I think its a simple logical error.

Inside the `while` loop you're updating `$day`, but the `foreach` loop continues to execute the rest of the code.

Better yet, you can avoid the `while` loop by:

```
if($day > 5)
    continue;
```

Comment: I'll give that a shot and get back to you! Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear if I do it using 'continue', the bottom part of the foreach loop doesn't get executed if day is > 5 - right?

Comment: Continue will continue the while loop, not the outer foreach. So where I have it, it is doing nothing.

Comment: @Ryan drop the `while` and try it using `if`. I've updated my answer.